# Change concrete class binding on demand in Laravel Service Container

Tags: laravel, inversion-of-control, laravel-artisan

How do I change a concrete class binding dynamically.

I'm trying to test an artisan command that consumes an external API.

```
class ConsumeApiCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $api_response = $this->client->request('POST', 'http://external.api/resource');

        $response = json_decode($api_response);

        if(isset($response['error'])) {
            $this->error($response['error']);
        } else {
            $this->status($response['status']);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently; I can fake the concrete class in my tests.

```
class FakeServiceProvider extends AppServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->bind(ClientInterface::class, function () {
            return new class implements ClientInterface {
                public function request($method, $uri, $headers = [], $body = [])
                {
                    return json_encode(['status' => "You've reached us."]);
                }
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Passing.

```
public function test_can_consume_api_if_authenticated()
{
    $this->artisan('consume:api')
         ->expectsOutput("You've reached us.")
         ->assertExitCode(0);
}
```

Failing; returns initially binded class response `You've reached us.`

```
public function test_cant_consume_api_if_not_authenticated()
{
    $this->app->bind(ClientInterface::class, function () {
        return new class implements ClientInterface {
            public function request($method, $uri, $headers = [], $body = [])
            {
                return json_encode(['error' => "Unauthorized."]);
            }
        };
    });

    $this->artisan('consume:api')
         ->expectsOutput("Unauthorized.")
         ->assertExitCode(0);
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the desire behavior this way? Or service container bindings can't change during the request lifetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am just leaving a code snippet for those that might be wondering how I solved this.

Basing on [Leonardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56337134/2732184), the source in the question is okay, but I had to manipulate the required interface manually, inject it into the command and add the command to the service container.

*I was not able to override the binding dynamically.*

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;

class ConsumeApiCommandTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_can_consume_api_if_authenticated()
    {
        $this->artisan('consume:api')
             ->expectsOutput("You've reached us.")
             ->assertExitCode(0);
    }

    public function test_cant_consume_api_if_not_authenticated()
    {
        // Mock client interface.
        $mock = \Mockery::mock(ClientInterface::class);

        // Here you override the methods you want.
        $mock->shouldReceive('request')->once()
             ->andReturn(json_encode(['error' => "Unauthorized."]));

        $command = new ConsumeApiCommand($mock);

        // Re-register artisan command.
        Container::getInstance()->make(Kernel::class)->registerCommand($command);

        $this->artisan('consume:api')
             ->expectsOutput("Unauthorized.")
             ->assertExitCode(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, do you know what replaced registerCommand() please in the latest versions ?

Answer (score 1):

It's always allowed to bind new concrete class to interfaces in Laravel. 
The problem I see here (and I faced in a similar scenario in the past) is that when you `bind()` the new concrete class, the artisan command has already been initialized (with the old binding).

In the `setUp()` method of your test case you should re-register the command so that it will take the new binding from the interface.

To test if this is a possible solution, just add `dump()` in the command's `__construct()` method and another one in the `setUp` of your test. If I am correct, you should see che command's one coming first and then the other.

Comment: You're right, currently am commenting $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap(); in CreatesApplication trait.

But am afraid this isn't the cleanest way to achieve this.